# Load balancing LDAPS to Active Directory using simple bind

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Can someone please help me with the following question

I understand from this article https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33547.load-balancers-and-active-directory.aspx that is not a good idea to load balance LDAP in AD because of Kerberos

However my situation is slightly different. I have an non-windows appliance that uses simple bind (password in clear text) to connect to the AD domain controller.

We then implemented LDAPS (certificate) so even though it is a simple bind it is now encrypted with SSL/TLS

So, if the client does a simple bind (e.g. does not use SASL) I presume there is no Kerberos exchange, and therefore the issue of load balancing Kerberos does not apply, is that correct?

Thanks very much in advance

CXMelga

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your understanding. The article you cite is speaking to Kerberos / NTLM authentication for "AD-integrated" applications. Authenticating to AD via LDAP is a different matter. I support a mid-sized (15k account) organization and have many applications authenticating to AD via LDAP over SSL through a load balanced virtual IP. The only "gotcha" is that each domain controller's certificate needs to include a SAN (subject alternative name) for the hostname you assign to the load balancer VIP. Not *all* LDAP clients bother with certificate validation (or, rather, some LDAP clients let you ignore certificate errors), but you'll spend a lot less time troubleshooting "LDAP problems" that are really trust negotiation problems if you use a valid-for-your-org certificate (this may mean a public cert vendor, including the Let's Encrypt free certs ... although I don't know that I'd want to renew my DC certs every 90 days, or may mean an internal CA that's trusted by all of the computers in your org) with both the DC hostname and load balancer address's hostname associated to it.

Comment: Hi LisaJ, thanks very much for taking the time to write back to me. My concern was if the LDAP Client tried to authenticate using the SASL (simple authentication security layer), rather than a 'simple bind'  SASL would kick of an attempt to authentication using Kerberos. So as long as a 'simple bind' keeps SALS/Kerberos out of the picture, then should be good to go?  Do you know what LDAP bind type your application use  when you say 'have many applications authenticating to AD via LDAP over SSL through a load balanced virtual IP.' ?  thanks very much

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply Lisa, I really appreciate it :)