# OAUTH2 LDAP over SSL via Load balancer not achieving handshake

Tags: java, spring, ssl, oauth, spring-ldap

I have an spring boot application using OAUTH2 and SSL.
The certificate for the Domain Controller has been installed into my cert store and I am using the correct ports and such.

Now, If I connect directly to the Domain Controller, it all works fine and handshake is good, as I am going direct

> javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|4A|RMI TCP Connection(5)-10.81.64.12|2020-10-28 10:11:36.950 GMT|ClientHello.java:653|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
> "ClientHello": {
> "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
> "compression methods" : "00",
> "extensions"          : [
> "server_name (0)": {
> type=host_name (0), **value=DOMAINCTL1.mydomain.com**
> },

But, if I go via the load balancer on the domain controllers then it uses the balancer address, which is not what the certificate contains, as the certificate is on the domain controller and not the load balancer.

> javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|4E|Thread-11|2020-10-28 10:17:02.340 GMT|ClientHello.java:653|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
> "ClientHello": {
> "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
> "extensions"          : [
> "server_name (0)": {
> type=host_name (0), **value=ad-dev.mydomain.com**
> },

Any ideas how I get it to recognize the domain controller as the certificate check, rather than the load balancer.

> org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: ad-dev.mydomain.com:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: ad-dev.mydomain.com:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load balancing LDAPS to Active Directory using simple bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63797026/load-balancing-ldaps-to-active-directory-using-simple-bind)

Answer (score 0):

> the certificate is on the domain controller and not the load balancer

The certificate needs to be on whatever is doing the SSL handshake. If it's the load-balancer (it probably is) then it needs to be there.

> how I get it to recognize the domain controller as the certificate check

This is impossible, and would completely break the security. You need a system with the correct certificates in the correct places. If you want the DC to be doing the handshake then you need a TCP-level load-balancer.